# Unable to fix the error "getToolkit() is undefined"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing Login Page using Eclipse 2022-09 & jdk-19 and I have done coding to display the frame on the middle of the screen. Below is my coding.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;

    public LoginS() {
        initialize();

    Toolkit toolkit = getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        setLocation(size.width/2 - getWidth()/2, size.height/2 - getHeight()/2); 

    }
```

I'm unable to compile the coding due subjected error. Same error for getWidth(), getHight() and setLocation() as well. when I use the same coding on NetBeans, it works fine. Only on Eclipse it's giving error. Need help please...

Is there any difference between eclipse java.awt.Toolkit and NetBeans java.awt.Toolkit?

Comment: no, there is no difference (regarding IDE) - How is the class declared? Is it a `Component` or a `Window`? (always better to include a [mre] for such questions - also recommended to take the [tour] and check [ask]) || BTW `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` can be used to center a `Window` (e.g. `JFrame`) - [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component))

Comment: No, I didn't do any special declaration. Just a normal class statement. Below is the code...


public class LoginS {

 private JFrame frmLoginSystem;
 private JTextField txtUsername;
 private JPasswordField txtPassword;

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     LoginS window = new LoginS();
     window.frmLoginSystem.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
I use this code to center....
   `int frW=frame.getWidth();
    int frH=frame.getHeight();
    int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    int x=(width-frW)/2;
    int y=(height-frH)/2;
    frame.setBounds(x, y, frW, frH);`
```

Comment: Yes, using your code, it works. Thanks. Also just wanted to know how to solve such errors? like said above is there any special declaration required?